# Can I make this React component State-less?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I has not state but it does have logic.  A simple mapping.  What is the process for making it state-less?

```
import React from 'react';
import BMFave from './BMFave.jsx';

class BMTag extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render () {
    const bookmarks = this.props.bookmarks.map((bookmark) =>
      <BMFave bookmark={bookmark} key={bookmark.id} />
    );
    return (
      <div className="bookmark_page" id="{this.props.tag}" >
        <div className="bookmark_tag_title">
          <p className="bookmark_tag_title_p">
            {this.props.tag}
          </p>
        </div>
        {bookmarks}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BMTag;
```

Answer (score 1):

Stateless doesn't mean no logic, it means no state. So you're already there.

Of course you can simplify:

```
export default ({bookmarks, tag})=> (
  <div className="bookmark_page" id={tag} >
    <div className="bookmark_tag_title">
      <p className="bookmark_tag_title_p">
        {tag}
      </p>
    </div>

    {
      bookmarks.map(bm=> <BMFave bookmark={bm} key={bm.id} />)
    }
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just move your mapping function outside the function. You could also leave it in, if you want, but that's not the best practice since it'd get recreated on every render (*I think*).

```
import React from 'react';
import BMFave from './BMFave.jsx';

const constructBookmarks = (bookmarks) => {
  return bookmarks.map((bookmark) =>
    <BMFave bookmark={bookmark} key={bookmark.id} />
  );
};

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="bookmark_page" id={props.tag} >
      <div className="bookmark_tag_title">
        <p className="bookmark_tag_title_p">
          {props.tag}
        </p>
      </div>
      {constructBookmarks(props.bookmarks)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your component does not have a state and does not use React [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) or [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), it can be a stateless component.

```
 const BMTag = props => {
    const bookmarks = props.bookmarks.map((bookmark) =>
       <BMFave bookmark={bookmark} key={bookmark.id} />);

    return (
      <div className="bookmark_page" id="{props.tag}" >
        <div className="bookmark_tag_title">
          <p className="bookmark_tag_title_p">
            {props.tag}
          </p>
        </div>
        {bookmarks}
      </div>
    )
  }

export default BMTag;
```

For more information, you could check this article about [Presentational and Container Components by Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).